# For if loop wont loop: any pointers to why that might be?

Tags: java

This is supposed to loop **24 times**; it does not, and I'm pretty confused as to why. Please help me various Kenobis out there :

```
private boolean simpleMove(Board bd)
{        
    int b = rn.nextInt(3);
    for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
        if (bd.isVacant(i) && rul.isLegalMove(tigerLocs[b], i)) {
            bd.swap(tigerLocs[b],i);
            bd.setTiger(i);
            tigerLocs[b] = i;
            System.out.println(i);
            return true;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(i);        
        }
    }

    System.out.println("invalid");
    return false;
```

Comment: It will run a maximum of 24 times, but you added a return statement that can be reached before that which will return from the method.

Comment: hey would that be return true or false? i thought had to have the return true in the body of the if statement.

Comment: After finding a "valid" move, should it continue to evaluate the rest of the `for` loop?  If so, declare a separate boolean that gets toggled, then only return the value of that after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments point out your loop will execute a maximum of 24 times.
But the return statement inside the if statement may cause it to return 'early'.

It looks like it's some kind of board game thing.
The board appears to have 24 'squares' and it makes the first legal move and returns true.
If it fails to find a legal move, it returns false.

I can't confirm the logic overall but that rationale seems sound:

If there's a move available, take it and return `true`.
If no move is available, make no move and return `false`.

Answer (score 0):

If you expected it to continue, even after finding a "valid" move, then simply store the fact that a valid move has been found.  This can be done in a separate boolean variable:

```
private boolean simpleMove(Board bd) {  
    int b = rn.nextInt(3);
    boolean valid = false; // until proven otherwise below
    for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
        if (bd.isVacant(i) && rul.isLegalMove(tigerLocs[b], i)) {
            bd.swap(tigerLocs[b],i);
            bd.setTiger(i);
            tigerLocs[b] = i;   
            valid = true;
        }
        System.out.println(i); // why output HERE when we have a return value?
    }
    if (!valid) {
        System.out.println("invalid"); // why output HERE when we have a return value?
    }
    return valid;
}
```

It's unclear if multiple "valid" moves could be found, and whether that would be a problem when you "swap" or not.  If there is only ever one possible move, then there would be no need to continue iterating with the `for` loop; simply `return` in the body like you were doing.